# How to share a variable to another component using a service in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I'm trying to send the data of the product in my virtual Store  which is in a variable to another component and get it in that component in order to  be iterate and add it in a table and show them to the user.
but i still don't achieve it.
I'm using a shared service 
Can anyone help me?

I already created the service and the necessary variables and the observable ones and inject the service in my child component which in charge of sending the variable to the another component but i get it undefined in the desired component.

This is the service with the variables

```
private productoAddSource = new Subject<any>();
productoSel = this.productoAddSource.asObservable();
```

```
 getProductoSeleccionado(producto:any){
    this.productoAddSource.next(producto)
    console.log("getProducto" + producto);
  }
```

This is my child component who i need to share a variable

```
addPseleccionado(form:NgForm){
    console.log(form);
    this.addproducto = form;
this.sharedService.getProductoSeleccionado(form);
    console.log("detalle producto" + this.addproducto);
```

```
addPseleccionado(form:NgForm){
    console.log(form);
    this.addproducto = form;

    this.sharedService.getProductoSeleccionado(form);
    console.log("detalle producto" + this.addproducto);

 enviarVariable(producto: any){
     this.sharedService.getProductoSeleccionado(producto)
   }
```

This is the desire component which is the shopping cart

```
this.sharedService.productoSel.subscribe(producto => this.producto = producto)
```

“i expect the object of my form exists in my component as a array to iterate it and put in a table.“
“Thank you in advance.“
“The output is undefined“

Comment: Where did you decleared the service ? In the root NgModule's class decorator or in the component class decorator

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just use the variable in child component, then passing the variable via @Input properties would be a good way. 
To share the data using a service is good when components are adjacent and data cannot be passed. 
To learn more about Input/Output properties referring to original Angular documentation would be best https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly subscribe to the `Subject` (in your case `productoAddSource`) in your child component if you don't make it private. 
check out the docs: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject